# Insert Arduino variable value into MySQL table

Tags: c++, mysql, arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I am trying to insert a variable value from Arduino into MySQL database table, and I tried different ways but it didn't succeed.

Could someone help me with this Piece of code below?

```
void loop() {

 unsigned long var =(millis()/1000);

 if(var%30 == 0)
  {

  var = (var==0)?1:var;

  char INSERT_SQL[] = "INSERT INTO Meter.consumption VALUES ("var");";

  MySQL_Cursor *cur_mem = new MySQL_Cursor(&conn);

  cur_mem->execute(INSERT_SQL);

  delete cur_mem;

  }
```

All answers are appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you need to concatenate the variable `var` with the SQL command. In order to do that you can use an auxiliar variable `query` in combination with the `sprintf` function for building the correct INSERT command.

Replace this:

```
char INSERT_SQL[] = "INSERT INTO Meter.consumption VALUES ("d");";
MySQL_Cursor *cur_mem = new MySQL_Cursor(&conn);
cur_mem->execute(INSERT_SQL);
```

With:

```
char INSERT_SQL[] = "INSERT INTO Meter.consumption VALUES (%d);";
char query[255];
sprintf(query, INSERT_SQL, var);
MySQL_Cursor *cur_mem = new MySQL_Cursor(&conn);
cur_mem->execute(query);
```

Note that although `sprintf` is an undocumented function in Arduino, it works similar to the one available in C. You can see more details [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/). Since it is a built-in function, there is no need to include any additional header in your code.

Comment: Thank you a lot it solves my problem, and there is one more thing which is the counter of millis seconds start from 79 on my LCD what do you think the problem is ?

Comment: You got it! I'm not used to work with LCDs but I sure other developers could help you if you create another question with mores details about this particular issue.

Answer (score 0):

replace this:

```
  char INSERT_SQL[] = "INSERT INTO Meter.consumption VALUES ("var");";
```

with:

```
  char INSERT_SQL[] = "INSERT INTO Meter.consumption VALUES ('var');";
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I replace it but there is nothing sent to the table !